# Create a Flash frontend for WordPress?

Tags: flash, wordpress

My buddy wants to create a WordPress blog, but because he's picky about the design (specifically the fonts), he wants to use Flash for the frontend -- display, content creation, user interface, etc.  He's looking for a plug-in that will take the user input from the Flash interface and convert it into the appropriate PHP for WordPress.  I've never used Flash, so I didn't know what to tell him, other than that this sounds nuts.  Is there a better answer than this?

Comment: dalejwilliams.com is attempting to do the same thing. I think he is trying to make an XML API for wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash can store and retreive information via HTTP easily enough, and I think 
Wordpress makes most things available via an XML-RPC interface, so you could
write a Flash client that did all the display itself and just used the
wordpress backend to save the data.

I'm not sure how this would, in any meaningful way, be "wordpress" though, 
rather than just a Flash based blog which used a tiny little bit of 
Wordpress's database.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this, I came across [this book](http://drupal.org/node/478200), which has just been published.  It deals with incorporating Flash into Drupal sites, which I know isn't strictly speaking what my friend was looking for (he specifically mentioned Wordpress), but maybe I can steer him towards Drupal instead of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that much work actually. I use the Zend Framework to communicate with WP and send the info back and forth to Flash. 
http://flashcms.patrick-segarel.com
I'm not sure this solution could be "packaged" into a plugin , it doesn't make anything simpler as such , it just allows to have a great CMS integrated with Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is old, but their is actually a framework made specially for that.
it's called press2flash and you can find it here: [Press2Flash](http://www.press2flash.com)