# Complete flash wordpress theme is possible? (with a php pipe of course)

Tags: php, flash, wordpress

Is possible to have the posts loaded into an swf using the wordpress framework? i mean, i want to write a post using the wordpress wp-admin interface and then see the result in a swf... I know that if i access using a php pipe the mysql server i can retrive the posts, but as i said i want to use the facebook framework... Is out there an allready made script to do this? any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Create a Flash frontend for WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973179/create-a-flash-frontend-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and there are a few methods to accomplish that. I don't know of any ready made scripts though. One of the simpler methods would be to import Wordpress' RSS feeds inside Flash and then parse them just like you would with an XML file.

You should be able to find a lot of examples of Flash loading XML out there.